# Is there any difference between normal distribution theory and least square theory?

Tags: anova, generalized-least-squares

Different approaches are available for determining the effect of an IV(Independent variable) on another variable. How the two assumptions cited in the question affect the estimates.

Comment: Maximum likelihood for a normal is least squares, but least squares is BLUE (via Gauss-Markov), so you don't have to assume normality to want to use it.

Comment: See the Wikipedia article on [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), or any decent textbook on regression. Least squares is a method, not an assumption; the conclusions you can draw from it depend on the assumptions you're prepared to make.

Comment: thanks Glen_b and scortchi. can we use least square method for a not normal setting ?

Comment: @subhash: You wouldn't be asking this if you'd read the reference. You *can* always use least squares, whether you *should* is another, & a broad, question; the answer to which depends on what assumptions you're prepared to make, & what questions you want answers to. I'd suggest if you have a specific case in mind, you ask about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Least squares is a method for estimation and does not rely on normality.
You get unbiased and minimum variance, as compared to other linear unbiased estimates, if the errors are i.i.d. (independent and identically distributed; see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_linear_unbiased_estimator)).
However, you need normality for usual hypothesis testing: t-test and F-test require normality.

Comment: @subhash: CV's for people to help each other learn statistics: there's no mechanism for senior statisticians to give their stamp of approval to answers, & little desire for one. Think for yourself: read the references, mull over what they say, check other sources, ask further questions on points you still don't understand. Accept answers that help you learn. Note also that an answer can be perfectly correct, yet your own understanding of its implications be dangerously flawed.